# BizTalk Batch Configuration Filter Not Saving

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

BizTalk Version 2010

I am trying to configure an EDI send batch but my Filter is not saving (or at least not displaying) after I start the batch

My filter is
`BTS.ReceivePortName == EDI210GencoExport_ReceivePort`

Before Starting Batch

[image]

After Starting Batch

[image: Before Starting Batch]

When I try to receive messages I get this error

> {ABF67403-4F99-4DED-BF15-30B0C9EE4666} 
>      {AC708D34-DCF8-4DA9-BE95-7DCE3A507F0D} 
>      FILE 
>      D:\BizTalkFiles\JohnDeere\EDI210GencoExport\ReadyForBiztalk*.xml 
>      Receive Location_EDI210GencoExport_ReceivePort 
>      The output message of the receive pipeline "EDI210GencoExport.ReceiveBatchPipeline, EDI210GencoExport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ffc03ec86640e930" failed routing because there is no subscribing orchestration or send port. The sequence number of the suspended message is 1.

What am I missing?

This is from the production version.
You can see the filter after the batch is started

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the context properties of the suspended message and see what the ReceivePortName property is.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the expected behavior.  The Filter is blank for a running batch.  UI bug?  Maybe, either way, it still read-only.

However, as I pointed out elsewhere, I don't think BTS.ReceivePortName is available for the Batch Marker component to evaluate.

More importantly, you do need to use the **Batch Marker Pipeline Component** to resolve the Filter to the Batch.